# update column in dataset using apache spark in scala

Tags: apache-spark

I have Titanic dataset store in datasets. I want to create new dataset from the existing dataset. Which will modify the `sex` column of titanic dataset to `child` if age of the person is less than `16` as follows.

```
def isChild(age:String):String={
  if(age.toDouble<16)
  {
    "Child"
  }else
  {
    age
  }
}
```

I am trying to create dataset using as follows:

```
titanic_df.na.drop.map(x=>isChild(x.getString(5))).show()
```

Any help as i want to modify 4<sup>th</sup> column of dataset based on age column 4 of the dataset and also handle the `NULL` values.

[image]

Comment: sample of titanic_df and expected output should help a lot, so update your question please

Comment: thanks for the updating the question :) its clearer now. see my updated answer below. if it helps please upvote and accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what is understood from the question, doing the following should help

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
titanic_df.na.drop.withColumn("sex", when(col("age") < 16, lit("Child")).otherwise(col("age"))).show()
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

looking at the example posted you want to change `null` `age` to `2` and update `sex` column accordingly, so you can do the following

```
titanic_df.withColumn("age",when(col("age").isNull, lit(2)).otherwise(col("age")))
    .withColumn("sex", when(col("age") < 16, lit("Child")).otherwise(col("sex"))).show()
```

Comment: that was helpful. Can you suggest how can i handle null in col('sex') for above query. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: You want to filter not null rows right? is sex column a StringType?

Comment: yes actually if i query like this
titanic_df.withColumn("sex", when(col("age") < 16, lit("Child")).otherwise(col("age"))).show()   it wont process column of age with null. that is fine with me. Above query worked. FYI, yes, sex column is a String Type.

Comment: Your updated question made it clear. please see my updated answer :) it thats the answer you are looking for please don't forget to upvote and accept. :)